# Access Database Unchanged

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add comments to a database. I'm starting with an Access database to be sure I have the code correct before going to the next step.
The two files I'm using are Comments.aspx and the code file Comments.aspx.vb.

Here's what I have so far. The contents of Comments.aspx are:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Comments.aspx.vb" Inherits="Comments" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Leave Your Comments</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style2 { width: 250px; }
        .style3 { color: #793300; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="frmComments" runat="server">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1 class="style3">Please leave your comments below.</h1>
 <table align="center">
        <tr><td class="style3"> 
            First Name : </td>
            <td class="style2"> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td> </tr>
        <tr> <td class="style3"> 
            Last Name : </td>
            <td class="style2"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr> <td class="style3"> 
            E-Mail : </td>
            <td class="style2">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
        <tr> <td class="style3"> Comments :&nbsp; </td>
            <td class="style2"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine" Height="60px"   Width="250px"></asp:TextBox></td></tr> 
</table>
    <br /><asp:ImageButton ID="btnContactUs" runat="server" Height="50px"
                ImageUrl="~/Images/Dark_Continue.gif" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The contents of Comments.aspx.vb are:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class Comments
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Private Property FNameParam As Object
  Private Property LNameParam As Object
  Private Property CommentsParam As Object
  Private Property EMailParam As OleDbParameter

Sub ImageButtonRun_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=/Test.mdb"

   Dim dbConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringSettings)
      dbConnection.Open()
   Dim commandString As String = "INSERT INTO Contacts(FName, LName, EMail, Comments) " & _
    "Values(@FName, @LName, @EMail, @Comments)"

   Dim dbCommand As New OleDbCommand(commandString, dbConnection)

   Dim FNameParam As New OleDbParameter("@FName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
      FNameParam.Value = txtFName.Text
      dbCommand.Parameters.Add(FNameParam)

   Dim LNameParam As New OleDbParameter("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
      LNameParam.Value = txtLName.Text
      dbCommand.Parameters.Add(LNameParam)

   Dim EMailParam As New OleDbParameter("@EMail", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
      EMailParam.Value = txtEmail.Text
      dbCommand.Parameters.Add(EMailParam)

   Dim CommentsParam As New OleDbParameter("@Comments", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
      CommentsParam.Value = txtComments.Text
      dbCommand.Parameters.Add(CommentsParam)

  dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
     dbConnection.Close()
End Sub

Private Function ConnectionStringSettings() As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

End Class
```

Absolutely nothing at all happens after I fill in the form and click the image button. Most of what I've read points me in this direction' but it's obviously wrong. Please help.

Comment: Are you pressing a button your form to post the data? Does F12 tools tell you that it is posting to the controller?

Comment: I hand wrote the code. I have no idea what the F-12 key would do.

Comment: I added an onclick event and a destination URL; but no data changed in the database. That is what I need most. Thanks vert much.

Comment: Yes - users will click the image button. Does this need a post added to make it work?

Comment: F12 is the web browser debug window (IE and Chrome at least have this and I expect the others do too). The easiest way to find out what what it would do is.... press it. Then go to Network tab and see if your window is actually posting anything to the server

Comment: Pressing F-12 is not the issue. When I open the table in the database, there is no change - no record was added. It would be much more helpful to pursue a different way to solve this insert problem than continuing the F-12 key discussion.

Comment: Pressing F12 opens the debugger which allows you to see whether your form is posting anything. No one currently knows if this is happening. If you learn to use the F12 debugger you will learn to help yourself and you will also be able to further information that might allow someone to help with your issue. To put it another way "Absolutely nothing at all happens" is not helpful at all, but knowing what your web page is doing behind the scenes may allow us to dig further into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your web page is posting something and actually getting to the class, try changing

```
OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringSettings)
```

to

```
OleDbConnection(connectionString)
```

`ConnectionStringSettings` is a function that immediately throws an exception (which you would probably see straight away in F12 tools)

Whereas `connectionString` is a variable containing the connection string

Comment: Thanks very much - I'll make the change and check back in with the result.

Comment: Any luck @ChickenMan?

Comment: None yet - been dealing with pneumonia.

Comment: Oh. I hope you feel better soon.